# how to configure new fontawesome icon to use it with ICON_TYPE enum

Tags: spartacus-storefront

need to configure new fontawesome icon, as defined in below url.
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/7a590dcee2e3cb3fee7a148c88adde2ab9adda6d/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/misc/icon/fontawesome-icon.config.ts
icon: fa fa-microphone

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the icon *type* with the ConfigModule. There are various ways to do so, I'm showing you an example with a so-called provider, but you can also use the ConfigModule or StorefrontModule to so.

```js
providers: [
  provideConfig({
    icon: { symbols: { MIC: 'fas fa-microphone' } }
  } as IconConfig)
]
```

Please not that I'm using the fontawesome version that has already been imported in Spartacus. If you switch to an alternative *resource* you must register the resource. You can read more about this at the documentation: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/icon-library/

You can then use the new icon type in a component:

```html
<cx-icon type="MIC"></cx-icon>
```

or as a directive:

```html
<button cxIcon="MIC">I LIKE IT LOUD</button>
```

In order to use the icon directive, you need to import the `IconModule` in the Angular module that host your component.